# Add Additional Custom Attributes in Template (Slightly)

Tags: css, design-patterns, aem, sightly

I'd like to use additional attribute when using data-sly-call

Here's the template:

```
<template data-sly-template.button="${ @ model}">
    <button data-info="Body"
            class="${model.moreClass}">
        ${model.label}
    </button>
</template>
```

When I use the button template, if there are additional css class that I'd like to add that the template does not have, what's the syntax that I should use?

Currently I have tried the following:

(1)

```
<sly data-sly-use.btnTemplate="button/button.html"></sly>
<div data-sly-call="${btnTemplate.button @ model= btnModel.btn}" aria-expanded="false" toggle-style="${model.toggleStyle}" aria-controls="${model.id}" data-alternate-aria-label="${model.altAriaLabel}">${model.label}</div>
```

(2)

```
<sly data-sly-use.btnTemplate="button/button.html"></sly>
<sly data-sly-call="${btnTemplate.button @ model= btnModel.btn}" aria-expanded="false" toggle-style="${model.toggleStyle}" aria-controls="${model.id}" data-alternate-aria-label="${model.altAriaLabel}">${model.label}</sly>
```

(3)

```
<sly data-sly-use.btnTemplate="button/button.html"></sly>
<sly data-sly-call="${btnTemplate.button @ model= btnModel.btn}" data-sly-attribute.aria-expanded="false" data-sly-attribute.toggle-style="${model.toggleStyle}" data-sly-attribute.aria-controls="${model.id}" data-sly-attribute.data-alternate-aria-label="${model.altAriaLabel}">${model.label}</sly>
```

All the above are not working. I was wondering what's the correct syntax?

I'd like it to render as:

```
<button data-info="Body" class="${model.moreClass}" aria-expanded="false" toggle-style="${model.toggleStyle}" aria-controls="${model.id}" data-alternate-aria-label="${model.altAriaLabel}">
            ${model.label}
        </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling an HTL template through a `sly` tag with `data-sly-call` will cause anything that you add to the attributes of the `sly` element, as well as its contents to be ignored. `sly` elements don't render, they behave like elements to which you add an unconditional `data-sly-unwrap`.

Given that you already have a template that accepts a model object as an only parameter, this is how you would use it.

```
<sly data-sly-use.btnTemplate="button/button.html" />
<!-- This is replaced entirely by the template's contents -->
<sly data-sly-call="${btnTemplate @ model=someModel}" />
```

anything beyond that (that isn't a `data-sly-*` attribute will be ignored.

```
<sly data-sly-call="${btnTemplate @ model=someModel}" attribute-added-here="won't be rendered" >This isn't rendered either</sly>
```

The way the template is structured

```
<template data-sly-template.button="${ @ model}">
    <button data-info="Body"
            class="${model.moreClass}">
        ${model.label}
    </button>
</template>
```

You can only influence the output by setting the `moreClass` and `label` properties on the model that you pass to the template.

Rendering this:

```
<button data-info="Body" class="${model.moreClass}" aria-expanded="false" toggle-style="${model.toggleStyle}" aria-controls="${model.id}" data-alternate-aria-label="${model.altAriaLabel}">
    ${model.label}
</button>
```

would require changing the template or creating a new one, to include the extra attributes.

Comment: toniedzwiedz is right, you need to add the attributes inside the button template, not in the outside `<sly` tag. You can provide the attributes dynamically using a map (see https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#223-attribute)